# Angular2 Routing not working when I remove id from parameter

Tags: typescript, angular2-routing

I have created HeroApp in which I display list of Hero from Service. When we select any Hero, detail of that particular Hero Display.
Here I have shown code:

**app.personList.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Person } from "../model/peopleModel";
import { PeopleService } from "../services/app.peopleListService";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-people-list',
  templateUrl: './peoplelist/app.peopleList.html'
})
export class PeopleListComponent {
  people: Person[] = [];
  selectedPerson: Person;

  constructor(peopleService : PeopleService){
    this.people = peopleService.getAll();
  }

  personSelect(person : Person)
  {
    this.selectedPerson = person;
  }
}
```

**app.personList.html**

```
<ul>
    <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let person of people">
        <a [routerLink]="['/persons', person.id]">
            {{person.name}}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When user click on hero it shows detail of the Hero and url change to:

> http://localhost:3000/persons/2

**app.personDetail.ts:**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { Person } from "../model/peopleModel";
import { PeopleService } from "../services/app.peopleListService";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-person-details',
  templateUrl: '/persondetail/app.peopleDetail.html'
})

export class PeopleDetail implements OnInit, OnDestroy{
    @Input() person : Person;
    sub: any;

    constructor(private peopleService: PeopleService,
               private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router){
    }
    ngOnInit(){
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
          let id = Number.parseInt(params['id']);
          this.person = this.peopleService.get(id);
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy(){
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }

    gotoPeoplesList(){
    let link = ['/persons'];    
      this.router.navigate(link);
  }
}
```

**app.personDetail.html:**

```
<section *ngIf="person">
    <h2>You selected: {{person.name}}</h2>
    <h3>Description</h3>
    <p>
       {{person.name}} weights {{person.weight}} and is {{person.height}} tall.
    </p>
</section>

<button (click)="gotoPeoplesList()">Back to peoples list</button>
```

but when I click on Back button, it doesn't take me to peoplelist page. Although URL also does not change.

**routing.ts:**

```
import { PeopleListComponent } from "./peoplelist/app.peopleList";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { PeopleDetail } from "./persondetail/app.peopleDetail";

const routes: Routes = [
  // map '/persons' to the people list component
  {
    path: 'persons',
    component: PeopleListComponent,
  },
  // map '/' to '/persons' as our default route
  {
    path: 'persons/:id',
    component: PeopleDetail
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/persons',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
];

export const appRouterModule = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Errors in console:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined
    at PeopleDetail.ngOnDestroy (http://localhost:3000/persondetail/app.peopleDetail.js:28:17)
    at Wrapper_PeopleDetail.ngOnDestroy (/AppModule/PeopleDetail/wrapper.ngfactory.js:14:16)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_PeopleDetail_Host0.destroyInternal (/AppModule/PeopleDetail/host.ngfactory.js:34:26)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.destroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12365:18)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.destroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12720:42)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detachAndDestroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12349:18)
    at ComponentRef_.destroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:7660:74)
    at RouterOutlet.deactivate (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4885:30)
    at ActivateRoutes.deactiveRouteAndOutlet (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4271:22)
    at ActivateRoutes.deactiveRouteAndItsChildren (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4231:20)
    at ActivateRoutes.deactivateRoutes (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4146:24)
    at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4108:21)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ActivateRoutes.deactivateChildRoutes (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4107:31)
    at ActivateRoutes.activate (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4094:16)
ErrorHandler.handleError @ :3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3491
:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3496 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
ErrorHandler.handleError @ :3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3496
:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3497 Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined
    at PeopleDetail.ngOnDestroy (http://localhost:3000/persondetail/app.peopleDetail.js:28:17)
    at Wrapper_PeopleDetail.ngOnDestroy (/AppModule/PeopleDetail/wrapper.ngfactory.js:14:16)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_PeopleDetail_Host0.destroyInternal (/AppModule/PeopleDetail/host.ngfactory.js:34:26)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.destroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12365:18)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.destroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12720:42)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detachAndDestroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12349:18)
    at ComponentRef_.destroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:7660:74)
    at RouterOutlet.deactivate (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4885:30)
    at ActivateRoutes.deactiveRouteAndOutlet (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4271:22)
    at ActivateRoutes.deactiveRouteAndItsChildren (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4231:20)
    at ActivateRoutes.deactivateRoutes (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4146:24)
    at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4108:21)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ActivateRoutes.deactivateChildRoutes (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4107:31)
    at ActivateRoutes.activate (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4094:16)
    at resolvePromise (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:665:31) [angular]
    at resolvePromise (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:636:17) [angular]
    at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:713:17 [angular]
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4396:41) [angular]
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:366:36) [angular]
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:166:47) [<root> => angular]
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:546:35) [<root>]
    at HTMLButtonElement.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:25) [<root>]
ErrorHandler.handleError @ :3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3497
zone.js:522 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined
    at PeopleDetail.ngOnDestroy (http://localhost:3000/persondetail/app.peopleDetail.js:28:17)
    at Wrapper_PeopleDetail.ngOnDestroy (/AppModule/PeopleDetail/wrapper.ngfactory.js:14:16)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_PeopleDetail_Host0.destroyInternal (/AppModule/PeopleDetail/host.ngfactory.js:34:26)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.destroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12365:18)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.destroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12720:42)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detachAndDestroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12349:18)
    at ComponentRef_.destroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:7660:74)
    at RouterOutlet.deactivate (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4885:30)
    at ActivateRoutes.deactiveRouteAndOutlet (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4271:22)
    at ActivateRoutes.deactiveRouteAndItsChildren (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4231:20)
    at ActivateRoutes.deactivateRoutes (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4146:24)
    at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4108:21)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ActivateRoutes.deactivateChildRoutes (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4107:31)
    at ActivateRoutes.activate (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4094:16) TypeError: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined
    at PeopleDetail.ngOnDestroy (http://localhost:3000/persondetail/app.peopleDetail.js:28:17)
    at Wrapper_PeopleDetail.ngOnDestroy (/AppModule/PeopleDetail/wrapper.ngfactory.js:14:16)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_PeopleDetail_Host0.destroyInternal (/AppModule/PeopleDetail/host.ngfactory.js:34:26)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.destroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12365:18)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.destroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12720:42)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detachAndDestroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12349:18)
    at ComponentRef_.destroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:7660:74)
    at RouterOutlet.deactivate (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4885:30)
    at ActivateRoutes.deactiveRouteAndOutlet (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4271:22)
    at ActivateRoutes.deactiveRouteAndItsChildren (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4231:20)
    at ActivateRoutes.deactivateRoutes (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4146:24)
    at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4108:21)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ActivateRoutes.deactivateChildRoutes (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4107:31)
    at ActivateRoutes.activate (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4094:16)
consoleError @ zone.js:522
zone.js:524 ZoneAwareError
```

[image]

I expect that I get peopleList will be displayed when I click back button.

Reference Link : https://www.barbarianmeetscoding.com/blog/2016/03/25/getting-started-with-angular-2-step-by-step-1-your-first-component/

Comment: anything in the console

Comment: yes. Actually so many thing in console but nothing related to routing

Comment: post the errors

Comment: remove the `ngOnDestroy` and try

Comment: yes after removing ngOnDestroy, its working

Comment: what is the reason to remove ngOnDestroy? and why should I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue is with `this.sub.unsubscribe();` in your ngOnDestroy, you are not initializing `sub`.

you should try below,

```
 this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe...
```

this will initialize `sub` with subscription, as a general practice I would also suggest (not compulsory) using a null check in ngOnDestroy,

```
ngOnDestroy(){
  if(!!this.sub){
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: Or create a RxJs.Subject called `ngUnsubscribe`. Then do `this.ngUnsubscribe.next(); this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();` in your `ngOnDestroy` and subscribe with `takeUntil`, for example like : `this.route.params.takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe...`